# SSIS - ETL, Staging, Control to contain database tables

Tags: database, for-loop, schema, etl, staging

I am new to SSIS. I am given a learning project but I am finding it difficult to understand the requirements. Can anyone please explain the following things in details. I am not sure where to start. If anyone can help please reply. I want to learn it.

1. Choose the AdventureWorks SQL Server 2012 database and install locally on your database server.
2. Choose a series of CSV files relevant to data in AdventureWorks (I'll leave this up to you but find something on Wikipedia or open data websites like data.gov, etc)
3. Create a separate database for processing.
4. Create separate database schemas for ETL, Staging, Control to contain database tables you will need for the SSIS packages.

I already have SQL Server Express, Visual Studio, SSIS Environment  and adventureworks setup on my computer. Your help will be appreciated.

Note: These are not the complete requirements. I can send more details, if anyone is willing to help and guide.

Regards

Comment: I understand this is your first question here. It would be worth reading through this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) which outlines how to ask questions here. You will have to be more specific about your question. Are you facing any issues in implementing it? What are those issues? Share your code and then someone will be able to answer.

Comment: I will post again... in small chunks. Thanks